# Lerna error: cannot find module during CI build

Tags: javascript, gitlab, continuous-integration, lerna

I have a monorepo using Lerna that I trying to build with Gitlab CI. Running `lerna run build` locally builds everything successfully.

The Dockerfile that Gitlab tries to execute looks a bit like this:

```
FROM node:16 AS common
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN yarn global add lerna
COPY . . 

RUN lerna bootstrap --include-dependencies
RUN lerna link

RUN yarn

# yarn build === lerna run build
RUN yarn build
```

Which results in the following errors:

```
Cannot find module '@project/common' or its corresponding type declarations.
import { SomeClass } from '@project/common';
```

Is there any step I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of lerna is being used locally? Amend your question to include the output of `learna info`.

`yarn global add learna` will install the latest version, which currently is v4.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by changing the Dockerfile. Running `yarn` before running `lerna bootstrap` and removing `yarn build` resolved the errors.

My Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
FROM node:16 AS common
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN yarn global add lerna
COPY . . 

RUN yarn
RUN lerna bootstrap --include-dependencies
```

I can definitely attribute the errors to my limited knowledge of Lerna, but I hope this answer can still help others with similar issues.